# How can I push both views ? Spacer() doesn't work

Tags: ios, swiftui

Im trying to push one GeometryReader as a button to the bottom of the screen but Spacer doesn't work here...
The idea is to make the app responsive to all screen sizes.

```
VStack {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Text("VeganFood")
            .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/12, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(maxHeight: 200)
    }
    
    /// Spacer doesn't work here

    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Button(action: { }) {
            Text("Let's get started!")
                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/30, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/7)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(20.0)
        }
        
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(maxHeight: 200)
    }
}
```

[image: Let's get started! button is centered, but should be at bottom]

Comment: Get rid of both `GeometryReaders`. Calculating font based on screen width is more common on web dev, on iOS, just use the [system standard fonts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font).

Comment: I used 'GeometryReader' because I would like a responsive app to all screen sizes. @aheze Is there a way to do this with GeometryReaders?

Comment: Well you should try to avoid `GeometryReader` whenever possible because they try to hoard as much space as possible. But if you must, then just use 1 `GeometryReader` that encompasses the `VStack`.

Comment: @aheze Thank you for your help. I've lost a lot of time trying to figure it out... I should come here in the first place instead I guess. Cheers.

Comment: yes, I know. I will always try to resolve on my own first :)

Comment: Also, please add your code as text, not a screenshot. Images can't be copied into answers, can't be indexed and don't work with screen readers.

Comment: Just changed it. Hope it's ok now.

Comment: @aheze just to let you know. I can't mark your comment as an answer because there is no code included that's why I don't see a check mark next to it. Just wanted to let you know as your answer has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- GeometryReader takes space as much as it can.

```
  struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("VeganFood")
                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/12, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 200)
                }
                
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack { //<= here
                        Spacer() //<=here
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Let's get started!")
                                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/30, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                                
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/7)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There might be some different approaches

[image]